# how to organize nested CSS selectors with brackets

Tags: css

there is any way that we can group CSS selectors with the same parent the way sass does? I am trying to write cleaner and more human-friendly CSS.so can I group the nested selectors without it giving an error?

```
.container{
    display:flex;
   .nav{
     align-self: center;
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What do you mean by "cleaner"? In your IDE? Cleaner CSS in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SCSS. It allows you to write CSS code like this:

```
<div id="parent"> Div_parent 
    <div id="child"> Div_child </div>
</div>
```

```
#parent {
    background-color: red;

    #child {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```